# ¿Como puedo agregar una etiqueta input submit con un onClick?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, contact-form-7

Tengo dos botones uno para enviar mi los datos de mi formulario con una etiqueta `input type"submit"` y otro para el seguimiento de google adwords estos funcionan bien por separado,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al yo llenar mi formulario me manda un mensaje con los datos del contacto a mi email [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el segundo boton me redirege a la pagina de gracias

y es este codigo `<button onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('https://ejemplo.com/gracias-por-contactar/')">Submit</button>` e igual funciona pero por separado cuando le agrego el `onClick` a mi etiqueta no funciona e igualmente si quito la redireccion del button

¿Alguna idea? se los agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza las clases de bootstrap para crear el botón en un span (clase "btn btn-primary" por ejemplo). Y lo demás por javascript.

```
<span class="btn btn-primary" 
onclick="gtag_report_conversion('https://ejemplo.com/gracias-por-contactar/');
$(this).closest('form').submit();">
Submit
</span>
```

Espero que te sirva